# Polymer novice, how to get require statement

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm having trouble starting with polymer. The purpose is (simple) ; an Express server that serve my index.html and the index.html that serve my polymer element.

And my first problem is : How do I use node_moduldes and the require statement inside of my polymer element. I think I found some leads, like Browserify or RequireJS, but it seems complicated. (And browserify didnt work..).

Could someone provide me a simple way to use the node_modules in this polymer element ?

I'll start with [my project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBO8w.jpg).

And the file :

public/index.html :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="import" href="./bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js">
    <link rel="import" href="./elements/neito-photoresistor.html">
    <title>Neito's Domotics</title>
</head>
<styl></style>
<body>
    <neito-photoresistor></neito-photoresistor>
</body>
</html>
```

server/app.js

```js
"use strict"
//require
var express = require('express'),
    path = require('path');
//Conf const
const _port = 3000;

//Server
var app = express();

//Middleware
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/..', 'public')));

//Routing
app.get('/', function (req, res){
    res.sendFile('../public/index.html', {root: __dirname});
})
.listen(_port, function (){
    console.log('Server listening on : '+_port);
});
```

and the polymer element him self (I know it is complete bullshit but still the require problem is here): public/elements/neito-resistor.html :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="import" href="./../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<!-- I know I cannot use the script src="" tag to import my node_modules -->
<dom-module id="neito-photoresistor">
    <template>
        <style>
        </style> 
        <span>Ambient luminosity = <span>{{lum_pct}}</span> %</span>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'neito-photoresistor',
            ready: function() {
                var mcp = require('mcp3008.js'),//I know that this line cause problem
                    can = new mcp();
            },
            properties: {
                lum_pct: {
                    type: Number,
                    notify: true,
                    reflectToAttribute: true,
                    observer: '_getValueLumPct'
                }
            },
            _getValueLumPct()
            {
                lum_pct = can.poll(0, 1000, function(value){
                    console.log('Luminosite ambiante = '+(100-((value/1024)*100))+' % ('+value+')');

                    return 100-((value/1024)*100);
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: You cannot import Node.js modules inside Polymer elements. The `mcp3008.js` module depends on some C++ code which makes this impossible even with Browserify and such.

Comment: Is there some kind of work around. I'd just like to display in real time the value I'm getting from my analogic sensor on my website

Comment: As a starting point, I recommend "Routing with Polymer and Express" by Wendy Ginsberg (https://wmginsberg.github.io/blog/poly-express). This article got me rolling on my app.

Comment: Okay I'll take a look thank you

Comment: It was inshgtful but dint mention how to use node_modules in front end

Comment: I believe you are going to need a specific backend process that will publish the readout for you. And with that you have lots of options (publish to db, some webapi, signalR, push, etc...). Polymer on the frontend can then query those sources for you. But once you serve you polymer app, you kind of loose control of it, it's on the client side already doing it's job so it won't perform any readouts on your end.